# Never ending transaction problems after mysql 5.0->5.6 upgrade

Tags: mysql, innodb

I upgraded our entire backend mysql db from 5.0 to 5.6, including changing a *few* tables to innodb, and we've been having nothing but problems with never ending transactions since. I still have a staging server that uses 5.0, and I can confirm that we only get stalled transactions on the new database server. Both servers are running in tx_isolation = REPEATABLE-READ mode (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set-transaction.html
). I'm pretty sure all the tables involved are InnoDB for both servers.

So a simple example of the problem we've been having is some process that sends welcome emails, which runs as a supervisord child (not really important). On the stage env with mysql 5.0, the connection lasts a few minutes and has no open transactions:

```
From show full processlist:
1639945 dbuser  <app-stage>:54536   db  Sleep   246     NULL

InnoDB transaction logs:
<nothing>
```

The exact same program on our production environment with mysql 5.6 and its suddenly the demon child that locks really important tables and never releases them.

```
From show full processlist:
28674638    dbuser  <app-prod>:54836    db  Sleep   67131   NULL

Innodb transaction:
---TRANSACTION 90461789, ACTIVE 67062 sec
MySQL thread id 28674638, OS thread handle 0x7f8ab934f700, query id 758722407 <app-prod> dbuser cleaning up
Trx read view will not see trx with id >= 90461790, sees < 89033402
```

When its not causing horrible problems, the transaction looks like:

```
---TRANSACTION 111578756, not started
MySQL thread id 42149496, OS thread handle 0x7f8ac29b4700, query id 975441865 <app-prod> dbuser cleaning up
```

Anyone have any suggestions? I'm sort of thinking about enabling transaction mode of read-uncommited but.... it seems like a patch for a different problem, and I really need to know what the original problem is!

Comment: Turns out a few tables where changed from MyISAM -> Innodb, changed them back. I'm crossing my fingers...

Comment: Also wrote some giant ugly script to watch for a stalled transaction, though it's a bit pointless now that the problem-causer that I'm keeping an eye on is using transactionless myisam tables.

Answer (score 1):

So I never quite figured out exactly how to trigger the problem, but it had something to do with really large innodb tables in one of our databases. One of them was over 303 million lines long. When I setup some scripts to remove old data every night, the problem went away for good. These really weren't very important tables, and were for the most part only written to, usually not read. They also all had too many indexes.

Anyway if you have this problem, try getting all your tables under 10-15 million entries.

Comment: I have been under the impression that MySQL is not to be trusted with large database / table sizes for quite a while now. After running into [obscure memory leaks](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40413/mysql-hogging-memory), full-text search index [mutex issues](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75439/mysql-instance-stalling-doing-sync-index) and [I/O serialization problems](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/64206/why-would-mysql-do-serial-synchronous-i-o) with InnoDB in 5.6 releases, I finally decided to give up on it for good.

Comment: Ya, it really had the feel of a database bug, especially because when you check what the relevant thread is actually doing, it's just sitting there sleeping (persistent connection). Thanks for the list!